# bloc build uthrow FlutterError

Tags: flutter, bloc

```
`../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_bloc-8.0.1/lib/src/bloc_provider.dart:103:8: Error: 'uthrow' isn't a type.
       uthrow FlutterError(
       ^^^^^^`
```

it was working with the previous commits even when I reverted the changes it showed up the same error here is how I provide the blocs

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<LocaleCubit>(create: (_) => LocaleCubit()),
        BlocProvider<LocationBloc>(
            create: (_) => LocationBloc()..add(InitLocationEvent())),
        BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(create: (_) => AuthBloc())
      ],
      child: BlocBuilder<LocaleCubit, LocaleState>(
        buildWhen: (previous, current) => previous != current,
        builder: (_, localeState) {
          // final GoRouter router = Routes().getRoutes(context);
          return Builder(builder: (context) {
            return ScreenUtilInit(
              designSize: const Size(360, 800),
              minTextAdapt: true,
              splitScreenMode: true,
              builder: (context, child) => MaterialApp.router(
                routeInformationProvider: router.routeInformationProvider,
                routeInformationParser: router.routeInformationParser,
                routerDelegate: router.routerDelegate,
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                theme: darkTheme,
                // home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
                supportedLocales: AppLocalizationSetup.supportedLocales,
                localizationsDelegates:
                    AppLocalizationSetup.localizationDelegates,
                localeListResolutionCallback:
                    AppLocalizationSetup.localeResolutionCallback,
                locale: localeState.locale,
              ),
            );
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

flutter doctor -v

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.4, on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
> 5.13.0-52-generic,
> locale en_US.UTF-8)
> • Flutter version 3.0.4 at /home/barq/dev/flutter
> • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> • Framework revision 85684f9300 (13 days ago), 2022-06-30 13:22:47 -0700
> • Engine revision 6ba2af10bb
> • Dart version 2.17.5
> • DevTools version 2.12.2
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 33.0.0)
> • Android SDK at /home/barq/Android/Sdk
> • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
> • Java binary at:
> /home/barq/dev/android-studio-2021.2.1.15-linux/android-studio/jre/bin/jav
> a
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
> 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
> • Chrome at google-chrome
>
> [✗] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
> ✗ clang++ is required for Linux development.
> It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install clang),
> or can be downloaded from https://releases.llvm.org/
> ✗ CMake is required for Linux development.
> It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install cmake),
> or can be downloaded from https://cmake.org/download/
> ✗ ninja is required for Linux development.
> It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install
> ninja-build), or can be downloaded from
> https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases
> • pkg-config version 0.29.1
> ✗ GTK 3.0 development libraries are required for Linux development.
> They are likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install
> libgtk-3-dev)
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
> • Android Studio at
> /home/barq/dev/android-studio-2021.2.1.15-linux/android-studio
> • Flutter plugin version 69.0.2
> • Dart plugin version 212.5744
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
> 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
>
> [✓] VS Cod
>
> e (version 1.69.0)
> • VS Code at /usr/share/code
> • Flutter extension version 3.44.0
>
> [✓] Connected device (3 available)
> • sdk gphone x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API
> 30) (emulator)
> • Linux (desktop)         • linux         • linux-x64      • Ubuntu 20.04.4
> LTS 5.13.0-52-generic
> • Chrome (web)            • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome
> 103.0.5060.114
>
> [✓] HTTP Host Availability
> • All required HTTP hosts are available

Flutter build apk -v

> [   +2 ms]
> ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_bloc-8.0.1/lib/src/bloc_provider.dart:103:8:
> Error: 'uthrow' isn't a type. [   +2 ms]        uthrow FlutterError( [
> ]        ^^^^^^ [        ]
> ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_bloc-8.0.1/lib/src/bloc_provider.dart:103:15:
> Error: Expected ';' after this. [        ]        uthrow FlutterError(
> [        ]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^ [        ]
> ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_bloc-8.0.1/lib/src/bloc_provider.dart:111:12:
> Error: Expected ')' before this. [        ]         ''', [        ]
> ^ [        ]
> ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_bloc-8.0.1/lib/src/bloc_provider.dart:95:12:
> Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'T'
> doesn't allow null. [        ]   static T of<T extends
> StateStreamableSource<Object?>>( [        ]            ^ [+6889 ms] >
> Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRelease FAILED [        ] FAILURE: Build
> failed with an exception. [        ] * Where: [        ] Script
> '/home/barq/dev/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle'
> line: 1156 [        ] * What went wrong: [        ] Execution failed
> for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'. [        ] > Process
> 'command '/home/barq/dev/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero
> exit value 1 [        ] * Try: [        ] > Run with --stacktrace
> option to get the stack trace. [        ] > Run with --info or --debug
> option to get more log output. [        ] > Run with --scan to get
> full insights. [        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org [
> ] BUILD FAILED in 14s [        ] Deprecated Gradle features were used
> in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0. [        ] You
> can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation
> warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
> [        ] See
> https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
> [        ] 16 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 14 up-to-date [ +365 ms]
> Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... (completed in 15.4s) [   +8
> ms] "flutter apk" took 15,826ms. [   +4 ms] Gradle task
> assembleRelease failed with exit code 1 [        ]
> #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
> #1      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:406:9)
>
> #2      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:184:5)
>
> #3      BuildApkCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_apk.dart:109:5)
>
> #4      FlutterCommand.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1183:27)
>
> #5      AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
>
> #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand. (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
>
> #8      AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
>
> #10     run.. (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
>
> #11     AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #12     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
>
> ```
>         [ +148 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 145ms [   +2 ms] Running shutdown hooks [   +1 ms] Shutdown hooks complete [   +1 ms] exiting
> ```
>
> with code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
flutter clean
flutter pub cache clean
flutter pub get
flutter build apk
```

I don't know why tho :). Hope it helps if someone stumbled on it